# Extract Specific Line Number in text file with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, extract, fopen, readlines

I have a file that is nth lines long and I want to extract line 10 from the file and read it in as a string. I don't want to import the file, I don't want to search for a string in the file, and I don't want to skip nth lines, I just want to read in line 10. I'm having trouble scripting this up, how can I do this?

```
fileID = fopen(test.txt','r');


fclose(fileID)
```

Comment: I am not sure you can do it, in MATLAB. Please refer to this post https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49028-reading-specific-lines-from-text-file

Comment: This post may be also helpful https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81115-how-to-read-every-nth-line-with-textscan

Answer (score 1):

If you knew exactly how many bytes into the file line 10 was, you could use [fseek](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) to skip to that offset in file.  If you do not know this, then you have no other option than to read line by line using [fgetl](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) and ignore lines until you get to line 10.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab can't find the nth line without linearly searching for eol characters. Even if a function did exist to go to line 10, that function would still need to read every line and check for eol.  You have to either skip n lines use fgets/fgetl or use fseek if you know how many bytes precede the line.